# Meteor "Welcome" tagline appeared in my project and won't go away

Tags: javascript, meteor

Not sure how the initial "Welcome to Meteor" page re-appeared on a project i'm working on but has this happened to anyone else? Trying to work through a tut on Meteor and everything was fine. I left meteor server running overnight and I came back this morning and the "Welcome to Meteor" with the click button message appeared on top of the project i'm working on essentially pushing the content down the page.

Has this happened to anyone before?

Thanks.

Here is a screenshot [image]

Comment: Correction there is obviously code injecting this I just can't figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: Sounds like a stupid question, but are there *definitely* no legacy .html files in your project that shouldn't be there?  like "appname.html" in the project root?

Comment: Somewhere in your project probably is another .html with <head> tags

Comment: @Sindis you are right I did have another set of head tags in the main.html file, but i removed it and i still get the same header. Here's a repo of the current state. https://github.com/MARS1/leaderboard-mars

Comment: @richsilv not that i've been able to identify and i've gone through the entire project which at this point is really small. I've even tried going into the .meteor directory but have read it's not a good idea to touch that directory in general. Thanks.

Comment: Well this 'Welcome in Meteor!' is obviously in microscope.html

Comment: @Sindis dude you were so right, i'm a dumbass. It was in the original .html file in the root, just like you said. That's embarrassing but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

I just searched your repository and found the string: https://github.com/MARS1/leaderboard-mars/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Welcome

Using a decent text editor or IDE you should be able to simply search through the folders and files of your project for the `Welcome to Meteor` string to reveal the file it's coming from, assuming it's not being stored elsewhere.